# How can I convert a string form of a list to an actual list?

Tags: list, string, read

I would like to convert these two strings

`"(a b c)"`

`"(9 . 3)"`

to these

`(a b c)`

`(9 . 3)`

I'd had some luck with the first one evaluating this,

`(mapcar 'intern (split-string (string-trim "(a b c)" "(" ")")))`
basically, removes parentheses from string, splits it to ("a" "b" "c"), then calls `intern`
to turn all the elements to symbols and yields `(a b c)`.
When evaluating this with `"(9 . 3)"` though, It escaped all elements and yields `(\9 \. \3)`,
this however, is not the same as `(9 . 3)` that I wanted.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Note that your question is related to the fact that: In lisp, code (the string), code (in memory), data (list, etc.), read & print representations, how lisp parse its code are all closely related.

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer and it solved my  problem wonderfully, you answered so quick that I had to wait  10 minutes to accept the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ELISP> (read "(a b c)")
(a b c)

ELISP> (read "(9 . 3)")
(9 . 3)
```

If by `(9 . 3)` you mean you'd like a cons, then my answer would work. Note however if you actually would like a dot, my answer not so much.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the similar `read-from-string` too, and/or linking to [`(info "(elisp) Input Functions")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Functions.html).